# Unable to get "mylocation" Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to get the "blue dot" my location coordinates and set it as the center of my initial mapview load. But I am getting a null pointer exception.

What am I missing here ?

```
public class GetLocationActivity extends MapActivity implements OnClickListener {
private MapView location;
private LocationMarker locationMarker;
private MyLocationOverlay locationOverlay;
private GeoPoint destination;
private GeoPoint source;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location);

    location = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.location);
    location.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    location.setClickable(true);
    location.setLongClickable(true);
    location.getController().setZoom(12);
    locationMarker = new LocationMarker(this, location, marker,
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.drag));
    location.getOverlays().add(locationMarker);
    locationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, location);
    location.getOverlays().add(locationOverlay);
    source = locationOverlay.getMyLocation();
    location.getController().setCenter(
            new GeoPoint(source.getLatitudeE6(), source.getLongitudeE6()));
}
```

Getting a nullPointer at `source.getLatitudeE6()`.

Comment: There is no Location Listener in your code and then you cannot get the current location. Please read this document: http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/basics/location/currentlocation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgetting my basics here :). I need to get my location using LocationManager.

```
lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            (LocationListener) this);
```